# How to make Select render correctly within shadow root in a web component?

Tags: select, material-ui, shadow-dom

I have an existing app that I need to use as a web component to deploy as a widget into a third party application.

I am trying to use Direflow to build the web component, but I am having problems with the dom rendering of Select MenuItem and Dialog.

The menu items render outside the shadow root, direflow suggests using RootRef which is deprecated and does not seem to work, I have tried using MenuProps as below with domRef
set just before the return,

```
const domRef = React.createRef();
return(
<div>
  <Select
      labelId="select-label"
      id="select"
      value="none"
      onChange={onActionChangeHandler}
      MenuProps={{ container: domRef.current }}
       >
      <MenuItem value="none">Choose Action</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="changeAddress">Change Address</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="addTravelPolicy">
                    Add Travel Policy to Account
      </MenuItem>
    </Select>
</div>
)
```

I was hoping that domRef.current would make the Select render in the right place but it renders outside the shadow root with no material styling.

Comment: Ever get this resolved?

Comment: The solution discussed in the thread here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69828392/mui-select-drop-down-options-not-styled-when-using-entry-point-to-insert-scoped

Comment: I assume you use MUI v5 in your app: There was some documentation added how to deal with the Shadow DOM: https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/shadow-dom/#2-theme