# mui Select drop down options not styled when using entry point to insert scoped shadow DOM styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, custom-element, react-typescript

Note that this is for MUI v5 @mui/material and **NOT** using v4 @material-ui/core

After finally figuring out how to make @mui/material styles show when using an entry point to emotion to insert scoped shadow DOM styles (see this post [How to create insertion point to mount styles in shadow dom for MUI material v5 in React custom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69813276/how-to-create-insertion-point-to-mount-styles-in-shadow-dom-for-mui-material-v5/69813517#69813517)), it turns out the Select drop down is not getting styled correctly for the Demo component which contains the @mui/material components.

Here is the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d8xtdu-s2cufr?file=demo.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Demo from './demo';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from '@mui/styles';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';
import { create } from 'jss';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const theme = createTheme();

class MyWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    const emotionRoot = document.createElement('style');
    const mountPoint = document.createElement('div');
    shadowRoot.appendChild(emotionRoot);
    const reactRoot = shadowRoot.appendChild(mountPoint);

    const jss = create({
      ...jssPreset(),
      insertionPoint: reactRoot,
    });

    const cache = createCache({
      key: 'css',
      prepend: true,
      container: emotionRoot,
    });

    render(
      <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
        <CacheProvider value={cache}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Demo />
          </ThemeProvider>
        </CacheProvider>
      </StylesProvider>,
      mountPoint
    );
  }
}
if (!customElements.get('my-element')) {
  customElements.define('my-element', MyWebComponent);
}
```

Instead of showing like this (in addition click events are not getting captured correctly, particularly cannot click on select box arrow to close it):

[image]

Dropdown options are showing like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `MenuProps.disablePortal = true` to mount Menu inside shadow DOM (to be able to use scoped styles)

```
<Select MenuProps={{ disablePortal: true }}>
```

Comment: It worked. I could not find info about this easily in the mui.com documentation. If anyone can point me to it, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: https://mui.com/api/portal/#props
https://mui.com/api/popper/